# How to use slots with a simple HTMLElement?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create and use a simple element without using the Shadow DOM.

I create it like this:

```js
customElements.define('my-card', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.innerHTML = `
            <div>
                <slot name="title"></slot>               
            </div>`;
    }
});
```

And then use it like this:

```html
    <my-card>
        <div slot="title">Some title</div>
    </my-card>
```

And what I get is:

```html
<my-card>
            <div>
                <slot name="title"></slot>               
            </div>
</my-card>
```

What am I missing? Everything I find online is using the Shadow DOM but I want this way simpler.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What are you using `<slot>`s for? They are meant to be an outlet that outputs the elements  with that slot attribute to then pop out in the node tree of a shadow dom. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with these. You are replacing your `innerHTML` anyway, so your original content will be lost. Also pretty sure this will result in an Error, as a constructed HTMLElement cannot have children or attributes during construction (which this would imply)... So many questions.

Comment: I want to define my own elements without using any shadow DOM functionality.
How should I do this, with simple DIVs?

Comment: If all you want to do is some HTML construction, do it in the `connectedCallback`, but `slot` will not work here. You cannot just 'keep the children you slotted' while replacing the entire internal HTML of the element, as the children will be gone too. The shadowRoot allows for a dom tree that doesn't overwrite your existing dom tree (so you can add whatever buttons and interface you need), and then allows slotting of existing nodes from the lightdom into slots in the shadow dom.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid shadow DOM?

Comment: @Unmitigated Because I rely on global styles for themeing. And some of these classes are changed and generated by pressing a button (dark/light mode), and I don't think there's any way for the shadow DOM to get these changes, is there?

Comment: Okay, then you don’t have a need for custom elements, you just need to output some DOM. You can do that but it’s not really a good way to use it, or even control it. Slots don't work like that, and there’s no real solution to your ‘problem’.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question, and one worth asking.

I did some testing, and I wasn't able to get slotted elements working without using the Shadow DOM. Maybe it's possible, but I tried several things and couldn't make it work. As soon as I attached the element to ShadowDOM, it worked fine.

I was however able to hook into user-created attributes on the custom element and use those to build the component. This is going to be more limiting than using slotted elements, but it may be good enough for some use-cases.

```js
    class MovieQuote extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.movieTitle = this.attributes["movie-title"].value;
            this.movieYear = this.attributes["movie-year"].value;
            this.quoteText = this.attributes["quote-text"].value;
        }
    
      connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = `
            <div class="card">
                <p>From the ${this.movieYear} film <em>${this.movieTitle}</em>:</p>
                <blockquote>"${this.quoteText}"</blockquote>
                <p class="html-title">Regular HTML attribute: ${this.title}</p>
            </div>
        `;
      }
      
    }
    
    customElements.define( 'movie-quote', MovieQuote );
```

```css
movie-quote {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
movie-quote blockquote {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
movie-quote p.html-title {
    color: green;
  }
```

```html
    <movie-quote movie-title="Goldfinger" movie-year="1964" quote-text="No, Mr. Bond. I expect you to die." title="title attribute text"></movie-quote>
```

Until reading this, I wasn't aware that it was possible to use web components without the Shadow DOM, so thanks for educating me on that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But I was looking, besides something like this, to have something like slots: tags that I can write while creating the element, which then the element processes and puts where they belong. And all other tags are ignored.

Comment: That _does not exist_ - and makes zero sense in terms of what you want to do. You cannot 'slot' into a light dom, that's just a DOM tree, so the best you can do is write your own HTML and move the contents around a bit. You cannot use it to 'slot' other things in the lightdom - how would that even work? How would you distinguish between your added structural nodes and the original content? That's what a shadow dom is for. Also @Josh Maybe have a look at `attributeChangedCallback` if all you use is attributes, as it gets called on construct and when they change!

Comment: @Desmes, What I'm proposing is more like templating than slotting.  The concept of "slotting" is more complicated and will require Shadow DOM. There's no getting around that.